# Vaadin Plupload uploads wrong filename

Tags: java, vaadin7, plupload

Anyone has come across this issue where the uploaded filename is looking a bit weird.

I am trying this [Vaadin Plupload](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/plupload-wrapper-for-vaadin-7x) addon which is a very nice addon. However, it uploads the wrong file name.

```
  //add file uploaded handler
    uploader.addFileUploadedListener(new Plupload.FileUploadedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFileUploaded(PluploadFile file) {
            File uploadedFile = file.getUploadedFile();
            System.out.println("This file was just uploaded: " 
              + uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    });
```

And it gives me this kind of file name **o_199r9ll9e1g6q15vmrdj13l51rdbl**.txt ...how do I get the **normal.txt** file name instead of such weird file name.

Comment: I haven't used this add-on, but I would assume that the supplied payload is uploaded to a temporary file with an uniquely generated name, which you can then move/rename as you like. The same seems to be suggested by their [github readme page](https://github.com/eXsio/vaadin-plupload) (scroll to section that reads `I'm uploading file test.mp3 .....`). If you scroll down a bit, you should see an option to use a `PluploadManager` to specify a folder so maybe that will behave differently. Unfortunately, so far I didn't have the time to check the sources and confirm any of the 2 suppositions...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I read that line, of course, but there is no different behaviour with `PluploadManager` and specifying the folder, it still generates that random filename.

Comment: What does this mean in JAVA code? "As You see, the field is parameterized. Thanks to this, You can use it to get ```java.io.File``` or ```byte[]``` as a value/type of the field."

Comment: It means that after the upload you can get hold of the uploaded file either as a `File` object or a `byte[]`, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My problem is how do I get the original file name instead of those truncated ones. Any code snippet would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this issue, here is the discussion for this specific [issue](https://vaadin.com/forum/-/message_boards/view_message/15518728#!/thread/15440640) from Vaadin site:

```
Path myPath = Paths.get(YOUR_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + file.getId() + (FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName()).isEmpty()
                        ? "" : ('.' + FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName()))));
                Path rF = Paths.get(YOUR_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + file.getName());
                try {
                    Files.move(myPath, rF, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    //refresh your tree table container
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.error("Unable to rename file" + file.getName(), e);
                }
```

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I am updating the answer with Vaadin discussion forum link.